# Creating a two decimal number from a float - not for display

Tags: cocoa, format, decimal

I having been using floating number types in some calculations.  I use NSLog to view the values in the console and they are appearing in scientific notation.  I want the values to be represented by two decimal places for the calculations...not the display.  How do I conver to two decimals?

Comment: What kind of values are you representing? Are they arbitrary floats or, say, currency values?

Comment: If they're currency values, I certainly hope that they're _not_ stored in floating-point objects.

Comment: They are not currency values.

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to perform [fixed-point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), then use `int` or `long int` data types to represent hundredths, and when you want to display the values, divide by `100.0f`. Also look at using `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the language, but one can usually do this using something like

```
int(n * 100 + 0.5) / 100
```

Be sure to check the available libraries for a function named `round` or similar. In Perl, I would just use

```
sprintf("%.2f", $n)
```

This does rounding and the result can be used as a number.

Comment: C is almost the same: printf("\nThe float is %.2f", yourFloatVariable);  You'll like printf better than NSLog; no gobbledygoock. For other printf modifiers, try this link: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Comment: @Wienke, oh, is he asking about C? No, that won't do at all in C, since he specifically said he wants to round the variable for use, not for printing.

Comment: You have the \n in the wrong place, unless you meant to print a blank line before that line and leave the line with the number unterminated. And what “gobbledygoock” are you talking about?

Comment: @Peter Hosey: I do mean to print a blank line before "The float is...", to set it off and make it easier to read. The NSLog gobbledygoock I am referring to is "2011-04-21 15:26:52.396 nameOfProject [2881:a0f]." I'm sure it's useful sometimes, but there's no way to turn it off.

Comment: He "use[s] NSLog to view the values in the console." printf is an alternative in C, which is available for Cocoa projects (it's the "C" in Objective-C).